# f(x) and g(x) are two polynomials, then choose the right option...

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two polynomials such that the polynomial $h(x)=xf(x^{3})+x^{2}g(x^{6})$ is divisible by $x^{2}+x+1$, then choose the correct option:

$A. f(1)=g(1)$

$B. f(1) $ is not equal to $g(1)$

$C. f(1)$ and $g(1)$ are non-zero, $f(1)=g(1)$

$D. f(1)=-g(1)$, $f(1)$ and $g(1)$ are non-zero.

What I did: Since $x^{2}+x+1$ divides the $h(x)$, $\omega$ and $\omega^{2}$ are roots of $h(x)$. Therefore, $\omega f(1)+\omega^{2}g(1)=0$ and $\omega^{2} f(1)+\omega g(1)=0$ which gives $f(1)=-g(1)$. But the answer is option $A$. Please help...

NOTE: $\omega$ is $e^{\iota 2\pi /3}$, $\iota =(-1)^{1/2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct that $f(1)=-g(1)$. But, as Ian points out above, we also have that $g(1)=f(1)$. Put these two facts together, and you'll see that the only correct answer is A!

Comment: Thanks... Didn't note that !!

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: I think you mean $\omega=(1)^{1/3}$. You're left with
$$
\omega f(1)+\omega^2g(1)=\omega^2 f(1)+\omega g(1)\implies (\omega^2-\omega)(g(1)-f(1))=0
$$

Comment: No. $(-1)^{1/3}$ doesn't satisfy $x^2+x+1=0$, it satisfies $x^2-x+1=0$. On the other hand, the manipulations you've got here are correct (and indeed are only true if $\omega = e^{2\pi i/3}$).

Comment: No, the minimal polynomial of the third roots of unity is $x^2+x+1=0$.

Comment: No.omega is the cube root of unity...

Comment: That's correct. $(-1)^{1/3}$ is not a third root of unity, it's a sixth root of unity.

Comment: Mike is right on the money.  There is an error in one of the answers above.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that $f(1)$ and $g(1)$ satisfy two equations which are linearly independent.  Hence $f(1) = g(1) = 0$.  That implies (A), as well as your answer.